# Zend append javascript url with parameter

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

I used Zend Framework to append Javascript file from other domain with some parameter, the URL is: http://my-js-lib.com/lib.js?rev=1.2&scope=all. But when I used this code in controller:

`$this->view->inlineScript()->appendFile('http://my-js-lib.com/lib.js?rev=1.2&scope=all');`

The result is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://my-js-lib.com/lib.js?rev=1.2&amp;scope=all"></script>
```

I do not want the "&" sign be parsed into "&". What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find my answer when I touch deep into Zend Library:

```
$this->view->inlineScript()->setAutoEscape(false)->appendFile('http://my-js-lib.com/lib.js?rev=1.2&scope=all');
```

Answer (score 0):

& is special html entity. [Check How to Write Valid URL Query String Parameters](http://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/)